# Can someone explain this Python operation: b[:b.index(i)]+b[b.index(i)+1:]?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I found an answer to the question:

> Write a Python program to make a new string with all the consonants deleted from the string "Hello, have a good day".

But I do not understand what is the meaning of this line:
 `b = b[:b.index(i)]+b[b.index(i)+1:]`

The full code:

```
a = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U',' ']
b = "Hello, have a good day"
for i in b:
  if i not in a:
    b = b[:b.index(i)]+b[b.index(i)+1:]
print(b)
```

Comment: Please clarify what parts of the line you do understand. Do you know what ``b.index`` is? Do you know what the syntax ``b[:a]`` and ``b[a:]`` means? Do you know what ``b[:a] + b[a+1:]`` means? Please also be aware that this is an extremely inefficient way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration `b` is updated, removing one consonant (or other character not in `a`) from left to right:

```
ello, have a good day
elo, have a good day
eo, have a good day
eo have a good day
eo ave a good day
eo ae a good day
eo ae a ood day
eo ae a oo day
eo ae a oo ay
eo ae a oo a
```

The function `index` finds the position in the list of the consonant (`i`), then all the letters before and after that position are concatenated together and `b` is updated:

```
b = b[:b.index(i)]+b[b.index(i)+1:]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U',' ']    
b = "Hello, have a good day"
c = ""                          
for i in b:                             
    if i not in a:                                 
        continue               
    else:                 
        c=c+i      
print(c)
```

Comment: You seem to have written an alternative program to meet the same goal, but the OP's question was "What does this line of code do?"

Comment: Read the question... it says "I do not understand what is the meaning of this line:
`b = b[:b.index(i)]+b[b.index(i)+1:]`" That is the whole purpose of this question.

Comment: As you've only been on Stack Overflow for a day, but have already posted four answers, can I give you some friendly advice? 1) Try reading a few more questions to understand the way things work before you post. 2) Read questions carefully to make sure you're answering the question that was asked. 3) Learn how to use the code [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) 4) Make sure your answer doesn't duplicate one from years before, 5) Never post code or data as pictures, always post them as text. Not following these rules is why you've only had downvotes so far (not from me).

Comment: I should have added 6) Don't just post code as an answer. If you want to get upvotes, explain how your code solves the OP's problem. If there are other answers, explain what your code adds over and above those other answers. Your answer then will be much more valuable to people in the future.